# Ovechkin's +/- in his recent hat trick game

Tags: ice-hockey, statistics, nhl

Alex Ovechkin had 3 goals and 1 assist in [Saturday's 5-1 win over the New Jersey Devils](http://espn.go.com/nhl/boxscore?gameId=400442724). The Devils only scored 1 goal so I'd assume his minimum +/-, assuming he was on the ice when the Devils scored, is +3 (4 points for - 1 against). But he is listed as +2. Is this a mistake, me being stupid, or missing something about +/-?

Comment: See http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/in-ice-hockey-how-is-plus-minus-calculated for more details about how +/- is calculated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Power play goals don't count towards the scoring team players' *+*. One of Ovechkin's goals and his assist were both on power play.